# What is the preferred way of interacting with Lottie files in a .NET MAUI app?

Tags: animation, maui, lottie

I would like to implement an animated Play/Pause button in my .NET MAUI streaming app.

For this I thought I might use a lottie file.

I am able to use SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui to load and animate a lottie file.

However, the control itself does not offer any kind of interaction such as Commands or an OnClick event handler.

Maybe I am blind, but what is the preferred way of transforming this "static" control to something, my users can interact with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide some interactions, i thought you could add some gestures on **SKLottieView**.

In .xaml file

```
<skia:SKLottieView
    x:Name="myanimatedview"
    Source="dotnetbot.json"
    HeightRequest="300"
    WidthRequest="300"
    RepeatCount="-1">              
    <skia:SKLottieView.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </skia:SKLottieView.GestureRecognizers>
</skia:SKLottieView>
```

In .cs file, implement the event handler.

```
void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello"); // do whatever you want here
    myanimatedview.IsAnimationEnabled = !myanimatedview.IsAnimationEnabled;
}
```

You could add different gestures, such as pinch, pan, swipe etc, to interact with users. For more information, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms gestures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Wow. Crazy. This is basically what I tried tonight and I was distracted from the fact, that my Visual Studio didn't offer .GestureRecognizer as an extension for skia:SKLottieView. So I thought, that this view might not derive from something that allows this extension. I put a StackLayout as a wrapper around the SKLottieView next and had this one extended by the Recognizer - which worked. However, now I tried your solution and it magically works. So thanks!!

Comment: How would I specify the Assets path i.e. where to load the png images specified in the data.json file from?